# Django How PermissionRequireMixin class works in code level?(I am even looking into mixins.py in auth folder)

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how PermissionRequireMixin works in Django. (I couldn't find any question explaining how PermissionRequireMixin works in very detail. I am looking into code 'mixins.py' in path of 'django.contrib.auth'.)

For example, if write codes like below, it will check if login-user has permission named 'test_permission'. if the login-user has this permission, it moves to a template which is written in template_name attribute. if not, it moves to login page(or another page depend on what you set up). so PermissionRequiredMixin check permission to move on in a class type view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ViewTest(PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    permission_required = ('pertest.test_permission',)
    model = Test
    template_name = 'pertest/pertest_check_list.html'
```

what I want to know is...

I looked into 'django.contrib.auth.mixin.py code to understand how PermissionRequiredMixin class works. I can see it is subclass of AccessMixin and understand what kind of methods it has. but I can't understand how it proceed to check login's permission. I would like to understand flow in code base. where should i check to understand process for checking permission fully?

I even want to know this.

Let's say a login-user 'A' has permission named 'test_permission' and the 'A' user is in a group which has permission named 'group_test_permission'.

```
case A : permission_required = ('pertest.test_permission',)
case B : permission_required = ('pertest.group_test_permission',)
```

in case A, a user A can move on because it has 'test_permission'.
in case B, a user A can move on because it is in a group which has 'group_test_permission'.

does it check a login user has the permission in auth_user_user_permission table and then check in auth_user_group table and auth_group_permissions? or in opposite direction? I am confused because group, user, permission are in individual tables and are connected to each other by ForiegnKey(ManyToMany or ForiegnKey).

In a nutshell, I would like to know process of how PermissionRequiredMixin class checks permissions and which part(what codes) I should check to understand this process.

Thank you in advance. Let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the authentication backends are responsible to grant or deny access.

As you might have noticed, the `PermissionRequiredMixin` in the end calls `has_perm` on the user object with the defined permissions. This method just wraps an internal method called [_user_has_perm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L180) in auth models.py.

Finally you'll might want to read the [backends.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py) shipped by `django.contrib.auth` to see how access is granted by default.

As far as i can see, by default it just checks if you have either a grant through your user, or through your group and let you in or not.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am checking _user_has_perm and backends.py. I think It need time to understand those part myself before asking more PermissionRequiredMixin process.

Comment: But, about 
'As far as i can see, by default it just checks if you have either a grant through your user, or through your group and let you in or not.'

I already knew that it check that you have either through user or through group. (I exercised and simulated situation like 1)A has permission in user table but not in group, 2)A is in group which has permission but not in user table and 3) A is in group which has permission and also has other permissions in user table) so I understood that Django check both area (either way, if user has permission or user is in group has that permission)

Comment: I hoped to understand how django check in that way in code level. I think there would be code which refer to records in each table for checking permissions.